# Can I call multiple groovy from one Jenkinsfile in Declarative pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a traditional Jenkins setup.It run around 15 upstream and downstream jobs to create a final software.So I was planning to convert this structure into Declarative Pipeline.

Method 1 - Create 15 Jenkinsfile for 15jobs and execute Declarative Pipeline
Method 2 - Is is possible to have 1 Jenkinsfile for all the 15jobs?
or any other better approach for this senario?

Comment: Completely agree with Jeff Bennett answer.

along with that Jenkins declarative pipeline has many build in groovy method to make use of. a nice [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) from Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

A single Jenkinsfile is meant to manage the complexity of the entire build, so 'Method 2" is probably the right choice.   You'd have a single Jenkinsfile, with multiple stages - some in parallel, some in serial - and when the unified build completed, your software would be entirely constructed.  Similarly, if any of the stages fail, the whole thing stops and you get a unified answer.